# Azure port forwarding issues - endpoint is open and an inbound rule was made, but the port is still closed

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, port-forwarding, endpoint

I'm trying to open a small server to host a dedicated server for Starbound, but no matter what I do, the port doesn't seem to open. I've added the endpoint in my Azure portal and made an inbound rule in the firewall, but www.canyouseeme.org still isn't able to connect to it. I tested a port that was automatically forwarded when the virtual machine was deployed, and it worked just fine (as shown in the images below), but whenever I try to add another port, it doesn't work. If anyone can help me figure this out, I'd be thankful. I've been working at this for a few days now and haven't found a working solution. I found one article that said to add ICMPv4 and ICMPv6 as inbound rules in the firewall, and so I did, but that didn't do anything.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5x4Y.jpg

Comment: Is there a process listening on TCP port 21025?

Comment: No, I should probably try that first. I'll get back to you as soon as I run the server.

Comment: Right. You need a process listening on that port before you can connect to that port or test access to that port.

Comment: Never mind, it's finally working. It wasn't before, even when the server was listening on the port. Thank you so much! Appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

From a [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/778833/azure-port-forwarding-issues-endpoint-is-open-and-an-inbound-rule-was-made-bu#comment983432_778833) by [joeqwerty](https://serverfault.com/users/19152/joeqwerty):

> There should be a process listening on TCP port 21025.
>
> You need a process listening on that port before you can connect to that port or test access to that port.